# Bouncy Castle DataLengthException not being caught

Tags: java, exception, bouncycastle

I am using bouncy castle to decrypt and trying to catch the DataLengthException that it throws. However, for some reason, the JVM does not recognize the Exception as a DataLengthException. Has anyone else had this problem?

Code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < transformations.length; i++) {
    try {
        cipher = Cipher.getInstance(transformations[i], "BC");
        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, certificate);
        return cipher.doFinal(bytesTimestampEncrypted);
    }
    catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e1) {
        // try the next transformation
    }
    catch (BadPaddingException e1) {
        // try the next transformation
    }
    catch (IllegalBlockSizeException e1) {
        // try the next transformation
    }
    catch (NoSuchPaddingException e) {
        // try the next transformation
    }
    catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        // try the next transformation
    }
    catch (InvalidKeyException e) {
        // try the next transformation
    }
    catch (NoSuchProviderException e) {
        // try the next transformation
    }
    catch (DataLengthException e) {  
        // This is the one I am trying to catch
        Log.debug("Input too large for RSA cipher, trans=" + transformations[i], e);
    }
    catch (RuntimeException e) {   
        // This is the one that actually ends up catching it.
        throw e;
    }
}
```

As you can see from the comments, the exception is not caught until the `catch(RuntimeException)` which I added simply for testing reasons. I have debugged the exception and set a break point on the RuntimeException. The exception is: `org.bouncycastle.crypto.DataLengthException: input too large for RSA cipher` however, when I test `e instance of org.bouncastle.crypto.DataLengthException` i get false.

Any ideas here would be very helpful.

Comment: As an aside, it looks like you are doing something crazy here. Is this for a real application, or are you just trying to figure out how to use Java cryptography?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the same class file is loaded by two different classloaders it will never be considered the same class, because the class identity is made by the class loader AND the full class name.

This is the only way I can see that an object of a class with the same full name would fail the instance of test. Check your workspace/runtime for multiple copies of bouncycastle jars.

Comment: e.getClass.getName() = "org.bouncycastle.crypto.DataLengthException"

Comment: No. To me it still looks like a DataLengthException. How do you know its a different type of exception?

Comment: Try e.getClass().getClassLoader() and compare the output with this.getClass().getClassLoader() to see if it's the same classloader. You might have two jars of bouncy castle on two different classloaders. Try this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResources("org/bouncycastle/crypto/DataLengthException.class") to see if there are two entries and where those jars are located.

Comment: If the same class file is loaded by two different classloaders it will never be considered the same class, because the class identity is made by the class loader AND the full class name. This is the only way I can see that an object of a class with the same full name would fail the instance of test. Check your workspace/runtime for multiple copies of bouncycastle jars.

Comment: So, sure enough, there are different class loaders. However, I double checked and there is still only one jar in the workspace. Do you have any ideas how to fix the problem?

Comment: post the output of this this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResources("org/bouncycastle/crypto/DataLengt‌​hException.class")  to see where the two classes are located

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/43155/discussion-between-jhadesdev-and-humdinger)